# Why do distributions tend to the one that maximizes entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, phase-space

It appears to be a well-known fact that a probability distribution on phase space will tend towards the distribution that maximizes entropy. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) on maximum entropy states:

"The motivation is twofold: first, maximizing entropy minimizes the amount of prior information built into the distribution; second, many physical systems tend to move towards maximal entropy configurations over time."

There is the [MaxEnt principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy) of Jaynes, and perhaps even the second law of thermodynamics.

Suppose we have classical phase space with $2n$ variables $x_i$, $p_i$. Given an energy function $u(x,p) = p^2/2m$, and a probability distribution $D$, one has average energy $U(D) = \frac{1}{h}\int dxdp Du$ and entropy $S(D)=-\frac{k}{h}\int dxdpD\log(D)$, and normalize by setting $\frac{1}{h}\int dxdp D = 1$. [One can use Lagrange multipliers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/337614/8675) to find the distribution that maximizes $S$, and it turns out to be $\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta u}$, the Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution, a Gaussian, where $\beta=\frac{1}{k_BT}$ and $Z=\frac{1}{h}\int e^{-\beta u}$ is the partition function.

My question is practically speaking, how does this work? So if I have an ideal gas, and I let it settle into equilibrium, I should have the distribution $D=\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta u}$ on phase space. Then I add some information: move this particle to the left, that particle to the right, I squeeze $D$ a little, or move it to the right. Now I've added, say, 100 $bit$ of info, i.e. the new distribution $D'$ has $\Delta S=S(D)-S(D') = k*100 \,bit$.

Will $D'$ just bounce back to the distribution $D$, perhaps releasing some energy?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150753/discussion-on-question-by-jackson-walters-why-do-distributions-tend-to-the-one-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.